# Subsets of R which are not Borel

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading measure theory and I have a doubt about Borel sets. Whether the non-measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$ are exactly the non Borel subsets of $\mathbb R.$ Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you considering the Borel Measure on $R^n$ or the Lebesgue Measure?

Comment: Lebesgue measure is the completion of Borel measure. As such, a non-Lebesgue measurable set is not a Borel set, but there are non-Borel sets which are Lebesgue measurable

Answer (score 1):

The notion "measurable" depends on the underlying $\sigma$-algebra !

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and suppose that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, then each member of $\mathcal A$ is called measurable, more precise $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Example: let $X = \mathbb R$, $\mathcal A$ the power set of $X$ and $\mathcal B$ the Borel $ \sigma$-algebra on $X$.

It is well-known that there is a subset $V$ of $X$ , which is not $\mathcal B$-measurable (Vitali !), but $V$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very terse answer:

Let $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[0,1]\cup\big( 1 + C\big)$ where $C\subseteq[0,1]$ is the Cantor set.

Since the measure of $1+C$ is $0$, for every subset $D\subseteq \big(1+ C\big),$ the set $A\cup D$ has measure $1$.

But there are more such subsets $D$ than the number of Borel sets, in the sense of cardinality. Therefore some non-Borel sets are Lebesgue-measurable.